# Estimating parameters in q-Weibull distributions on Matlab

Tags: matlab, parameters, estimation, fsolve

I am trying to test if the q-Weibull distribution is better at describing the behavior of certain data than other distributions. Since I am from a biological sciences background, math and coding are not my stronger suits, and I have been struggling a little bit with implementing such analysis. I am basing my analysis on a paper on the subject of estimating the parameters of q-Weibull distributions. The paper states that to estimate the parameters I have to equate the following equations to zero and solve the resulting system:
[According to the paper, since the equations are nonlinear, a closed form cannot be found and optimizers need to be used to find the minimum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI6nI.png)

I have read the Matlab documentation, and I found the function fsolve to solve nonlinear equations. The problem is that there is a sum of multiple terms in those equations. Normally, I would use a for loop or a "sum" to solve those, but I have no idea how to make that within a fsolve function.
Any insights on how to do it? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Sincerely,
Leo.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to solve the nonlinear equations from first principles, MATLAB has a built-in Weibull fit function. Read
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/weibull-distribution.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/wblfit.html

Comment: The q-Weibull distribution is a generalization of the Weibull distribution. According to what I've read, the built-in Weibull function should not work in this case (unfortunately). The paper "q-exponential, Weibull, and q-Weibull
distributions: an empirical analysis" by Picoli et al. has more information on the subject if you are interested. Any advice on how to implement those calculations in Matlab would be appreciated. I still haven't figured that out.